# Netlify-hosted Next.js API returning 502 error for all APIs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, netlify

I'm currently hosting a Next.js application on Netlify, and I've encountered a puzzling issue with my API routes. When I attempt to access any of my API routes from the client-side, I'm consistently receiving a 502 Bad Gateway error in the console. This issue does not occur when I run the application locally. The error message in the console is as follows:

```
GET https://example.com/api/testApi 502
```

I've double-checked my code, environment variables, and the Netlify configuration, but I can't seem to pinpoint the root cause of this problem. It's affecting ALL my API routes, not just one specific route.

Here are a few details about my setup:

My environment variables are correctly set in the Netlify environment.
My local development environment works perfectly, and I can access the API routes without any issues.
Is there anything I might be overlooking or any common pitfalls related to Netlify-hosted Next.js applications that could cause this 502 error? I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions to help diagnose and resolve this issue.

here are the codes i am using :
for the api/testApi code: note this code is inside pages/api/testApi

```
// pages/api/testApi.js

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, OPTION",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Hello World" })
    };
    return response;
  };
```

for the Frontend code TestButton.js

```
// components/TestButton.js

import { useState } from 'react';

const TestButton = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const testApi = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/testApi');
      const data = await response.json();
      setMessage(data.message);
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage('An error occurred.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={testApi}>Test API</button>
      <p>{message}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestButton;
```

my current netlify.toml:

```
[build]
  command = "next build"
  publish = ".next"

[[plugins]]
  package = "@netlify/plugin-nextjs"

[functions]
  included_files = [".next/*.json"]
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am experiencing the same recently.

Comment: Found the error - in my case the error reason was directly in the api response:  I had switched to ESM by setting `"type": "module"` in package.json. This was somehow not running on netlify. I switched back...